# Determine if script is being piped to in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin, piping

If my script needs to behave differently when it is being piped to versus when it is being called normally, how can I determine whether or not it is being piped to? This is necessary for avoiding hanging. I am not talking about merely checking whether or not `stdin` is empty or not.

Comment: Why do you specifically care whether the input is a *pipe*? What is it about pipes that makes your program need to behave differently? Should your program do different things for `python yourprog.py < input.txt` and `cat input.txt | python yourprog.py`?

Comment: @user2357112 Is that really necessary to know? I explained why I want to, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can test if your program's input is connected to a tty, which may help, depending on your use case:

`$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.isatty())'
True
$ echo hi | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.isatty())'
False
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.isatty())' < foo
False`

Comment: That gives false positives for non-pipe input redirection, such as input from a file.